# How we call button clicklister of chlid layout ExpendableListView

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

By using ExpendableListView with different child layout that is consist of two button and one EditText how register these button onclick event to main activity,how we implement,thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the ExpandableListView.setOnChildClickListener

Inside the method onChildClick, you will have both the Group ID and Child ID as parameters. Using these 2 indexes, you have to put your logic inside onChildClick.

Comment: thanks to reply.i have implement this logic when i put button inside child layout then onChildClick not fire

Comment: You have to put the seOnChildClickListener in the onCreateView of the activity, not inside child layout.

Comment: Yes i put setOnChildClickListner oncrearte but it not fire.have another solution?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to register onclick of buttons in MainActivity.

You can set `onClickListner` it in your Custom Adapter's `getView(...)` method

Comment: thanks to reply.can you have any idea how we implement this event because onclick  button i open another drawer layout.Any seggestion?

Comment: i follow this link   http://www.techiecommunity.net/Android/Android-ExpandableListView-Layout-Example